# Content not updated when selected in sidebar menu

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing my first PWA with react and Ionic. I just started with the sidebar template. However, I'm stuck at the routing.

In my  `App.tsx` file I added this:

```
<IonApp>
  <IonReactRouter>
    <IonSplitPane contentId="main">
      <Menu />
      <IonRouterOutlet id="main">
        <Route path="/widget" component={Widgets} exact />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/widgets" exact />
      </IonRouterOutlet>
    </IonSplitPane>
  </IonReactRouter>
</IonApp>
```

If I select the "widgets" page in the menu, the URL changet to `/widgets`, but the UI does not update. It still looks like this:

[image]

I'm sure, that my widget page works. 
Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/widget` vs `/widgets` i think you have a spelling error